# Let chat messages appear below each other

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm building a chat window and I got the UI working well. My css skills aren't that developed though and my messages are not appearing as I had hoped.

I had hoped that my messages would appear like on a Facebook or whatsapp chat: My messages to the right and the other people their messages on the left and according to the time they were posted. I manage to place them on the right and the left but it isn't according to the time that they were sent as you see below. I post 5 messages myself and when the other person posts his first one it end up on the left side on top instead of lower than the other 5 on the left side. How do I make them appear in the right order?

[image]

**CSS file**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Nunito';
}

h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #575ed8;
}


#movie-chat{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#chat-window{
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

.chat-message {
    width: 45%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.rightAligned {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.leftAligned {
    float: leftt;
    clear: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

#output p{
    padding: 14px 0px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    color: #555;
}

label{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

#fullName {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

input {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #eee;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    font-family: Nunito;
    font-size: 16px;
}

button{
    background: #575ed8;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 12px 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
}
```

**Html file**

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<div id="movie-chat">
    <h2>Movie Chat</h2>
    <div id="chat-window">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li
            [ngClass]="{
                'leftAligned': !isItMyMsg(message.fullName),
                'rightAligned': isItMyMsg(message.fullName)
            }"
            *ngFor="let message of messages"
            class="list-group-item chat-message"
        >
            <p>{{message.fullName}}</p>
            <p>{{message.message}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <p id="fullName">{{fullName}}</p>
    <input (keyup.enter)="sendMessageToServer(messageInput.value)" id="message" type="text" #messageInput placeholder="Message" />
    <button (click)="sendMessageToServer(messageInput.value)" id="send">Send</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your code (HTML and CSS) as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can replicate the situation and help you solve your issue.

Comment: Oops, forgot the most important part. I added the CSS and html template.

Comment: Have you tried removing the superfluous "t" in `float: leftt:` on your `.leftAligned` ruleset? If that isn't part of the issue there are solutions to get to the result you want.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you